# Vercel deployment does not work as in local

Tags: node.js, vercel

I do have a project on my local machine which I successfully run using `npm run dev`.

The project is connected to GitLab and consists solely of the `main` branch.
In Vercel, I did import the project from GitLab, but the deployment seems to have issues (I think it is related to the database, but probably this is not relevant, as the same operation works on my machine).

I tried editing the general settings of the deployment, i.e. setting the build options to `npm run dev` or `npx prisma generate && next build`, but it does not change anything. Any ideas?